# Is $\varphi$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Define $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$ by $\varphi(a,b)=[a+b]_6$.

---

To show $\varphi$ preserves addition,

$\hspace{100pt} \varphi((a,b)+(c,d))=\varphi((a,b))+\varphi((c,d))$.

$\varphi((a,b)+(c,d))=\varphi((a+c),(b+d))=[a+c]_6+[b+d]_6$

$\hspace{73pt}$$=[a+b]_6+[c+d]_6=\varphi((a,b))+\varphi((c,d))$

$\\$

To show $\varphi$ preserves multiplication,

$\hspace{100pt} \varphi((a,b)\cdot(c,d))=\varphi((a,b))\cdot\varphi((c,d))$.

$\varphi((a,b)\cdot(c,d))=\varphi(ac,bd)=[ac]_6+[bd]_6$

$\varphi((a,b))\cdot \varphi((c,d))=[a+b]_6\cdot[c+d]_6=[(a+b)\cdot(c+d)]_6=[ac+ad+bc+bd]_6$

$\\$

---

From what I can tell, multiplication is not preserved. However, my book says that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism, so either multiplication must be preserved or the book is wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: Its not a ring homomorphism, it is a group homomorphism. So it's not necessary to preserve multiplication.

Comment: The codomain is $\mathbb{Z_6}$ which is a group under addition not multiplication. So $\phi$ is a function under addition not multiplication.

Comment: My mistake, the book says it is a ring homomorphism. I should have been more specific.

Comment: What book is that, @TheMobiusLoops ?

Comment: @DonAntonio A First Course in Abstract Algebra by Anderson and Feil

Comment: I don't have it. Could it be that book is defining a *different* product on $\;\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\;$ and not the usual coordinatewise one?

Comment: All of the examples in the book define the product as I have done. Perhaps it is just a typo as it only says "Yes" or "No" in the solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this $\phi$ is not a ring homomorphism, only a homomorphism between the underlying ableian groups. Consider for example $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, then $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$ so
$$\phi((1,0)\cdot(0,1))=[0]_6\ \ne \  [1]_6=\phi(1,0)\cdot\phi(0,1)\,.$$